# trying to create a flag like object with multiple colors

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create an object that looks like a FLAG with black and white stripes running horizontally and veritcally, like a finish line at the end of a race.

I need a way to color my flag (so it the inner rectangles a filled with black and white) which is a CubeGeometry looks like the image attached below, I am unable to figure out how to color this flag with multiple colors so it resembles a finish line flag (common to many racing games)

[image]

this the code for the Flag,

```
Flag = function(){
    this.body = new THREE.Group();

    var polegeom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.5, 0.5, 50, 20, 1);
    this.pole = new THREE.Mesh(polegeom, pinkMat);
    this.pole.position.x = +30;
    this.pole.position.y = +20;
    this.pole.position.z = -50;
    this.pole.castShadow = false;
    this.body.add(this.pole);

    var planegeom = new THREE.CubeGeometry(20, 10, 0.5, 10, 10);
    this.flag = new THREE.Mesh(planegeom, flagMat);
    this.flag.position.x = 10;
    this.flag.position.y = 20;
    this.flag.position.z = 0;
    this.pole.add(this.flag);
}
```

```
function createFlag() {
    var pole = new Flag();
    scene.add(pole.body);
}
```

```
window.addEventListener('load', init, false);

function loop(){
    render();
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

function init(event) {
    initScreenAnd3D();
    createLights();
    createFlag();
    loop();
}
```

Edit :
Found a way to get the solution,

```
var floorTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/checkerboard.jpg' );

var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( 
        { map: floorTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide} 
    );
```

```
this.flag = new THREE.Mesh(planegeom, floorMaterial);
this.pole.add(this.flag);
```